# Set custom timer for Slick slideshow based on field value

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I have a Slick slideshow. My nodes have a **Timer** field. Right now, I am setting the time of the slick slide like so:

```
Drupal.behaviors.mrpeanut = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    var $slider = $("#slick-views-slideshow-page-1-slider");
    $slider.once('mrpeanut').on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
            slideTime = $('div.slide--' + slick.currentSlide + ' div.field--name-field-timer').text();
            $slider.slick("setOption", "autoplaySpeed", slideTime);
        });
  }
}
```

However, I had some feedback that I may be better off to preprocess the field then attach a JS settings array with all the timer values. This is what I started piecing together based on some discussion in Slack (thanks, @nikathone).

In **mrpeanut.module**:

```
function mrpeanut_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mrpeanut/mrpeanut';
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $slideTime = $node->hasField('field_timer') ? $node->get('field_timer')->value : 20000;
    $slideTime = $slideTime * 1000; // Convert milliseconds to seconds
    $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['slideTime'][$node->id()] = $slideTime;
}
```

In **mrpeanut.js**:

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.mrpeanut = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            var $slider = $("#slick-views-slideshow-page-1-slider");
            var slideTime = drupalSettings.slideTime;

            // Get Node ID from the article
            var nodeAbout = $('.slide').find('article').attr('about');
            var nodeID = nodeAbout.substring(6, $('.slide').find('article').attr('about').length);

            $slider.once('mrpeanut').on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
                $slider.slick("setOption", "autoplaySpeed", slideTime);
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

However, it's not actually setting the correct timer values. One issue I'm having is that I need to capture *all* Node IDs from the view (whereas now I am only getting the first). Second, I'm setting the time slide on the afterChange instead of initially all-at-once.

Comment: I have test your code, I think this not gonna work because `['#attached']` should added to `render array` if you try it in `hook_form_alter` for example `$form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['slideTime'] = $slideTime;`  it works.

Comment: It's part of a view. Would it work if I somehow put my code in the view?

Comment: View, which hook ?or maybe you can move your code to the `hook_page_attachments(array &$page)`  to attach library to entire page: something like ```$page['#attached']['library'][] = 'mrpeanut/mrpeanut';```  you will need the `field_timer` value ;( !

Comment: The library is getting attached properly... I think the issue is that the field_timer value is getting added to a new array with each node load (from `preprocess_node`) instead of to the same array (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final **mrpeanut.js**:

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.mrpeanut = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            var slider = $("#slick-views-slideshow-page-1-slider");
            var slideTime = drupalSettings.slideTime;
            var nodeIdArray = []
            $('article').each(function(i){
                var nodeAbout = $(this).attr('about');
                var nodeID = nodeAbout.substring(6, $(this).attr('about').length);
                nodeIdArray.push(nodeID);
            });

            slider.once('mrpeanut').on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
                slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplaySpeed', slideTime[nodeIdArray[currentSlide]], true);
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```